# How to round off time to the nearest quarter and half-an-hour interval?

Tags: java, date, time, rounding

Any idea on how to modify the following snippet to make it work for both quarter and half-an-hour intervals?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateFormatUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat;

public class DateRounding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FastDateFormat formatter = DateFormatUtils.ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT;

        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println("now = " + formatter.format(now));       

        // Get nearest second
        Date nearestSecond = DateUtils.round(now, Calendar.SECOND);
        System.out.println("nearestSecond = " + formatter.format(nearestSecond));

        // Get nearest minute
        Date nearestMinute = DateUtils.round(now, Calendar.MINUTE);
        System.out.println("nearestMinute = " + formatter.format(nearestMinute));

        // Get nearest hour
        Date nearestHour   = DateUtils.round(now, Calendar.HOUR);
        System.out.println("nearestHour = " + formatter.format(nearestHour));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quarter are 15 minutes = 15*60*1000 milliseconds. You could add half of this to the long value of a `Date`, divide by it and multiply again.

Similarly for an half hour.

Maybe you can even do

```
DateUtils.round(now, 15*60*1000);
```

For this, Consult the [API doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#round%28java.util.Date,%20int%29).

Comment: Hi! Thanks! The first solution works, however, may I ask you to help me with your second one, i.e. DateUtils.round(now, 15*60*1000);, as it seems more compact and elegant? At the moment, the latter doesn't work at all.

Comment: @eualin - Not knowing the DateUtils API, I nevertheless think that the second argument to round is a number of milliseconds to round. In this case, Calendar.SECOND would be 1000, Calendar.Minute 60000, and so on. Perhaps you can even write `15*Calendar.MINUTE`. But this should be in the API doc - you **do** read the docs of the APIs you use, don't you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but `15 * Calendar.MINUTE` doesn't work either? Any idea?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What does "either" mean, i.e. what else "doesn't work" and how? Could you cite the java doc for `DateUtils.round`, it looks like you have difficulties to interpret it?

Comment: I do know how to read the java doc. The second solution, i.e. `DateUtils.round(now, 15*Calendar.MINUTE);`, doesn't work. In fact, I get the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The field 180 is not supported` Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I have the following idea: If the round() method does not take milliseconds as 2nd argument, then you a) either look for another method that does or b) you do it with the add-divide-multiply solution   I described before.